# Android widget service works only until API9 why?

Tags: android, service, rss, widget

Can some one please help me to analize why this code that is a widget service only work @ api 8,9 and 10? this don´t work on android API 17 4.2.2, also ocurrs an error when install.

When i run on 2.3.3 terminal it runs perfetcly and the show the feed!

the logcat i got when running on 4.2.2 terminal is this:

```
12-13 22:00:27.907: D/widget(1438): onUpdate()
12-13 22:00:27.957: D/widget(1438): Beginning update cycle...
12-13 22:00:28.017: D/AndroidRuntime(1438): Shutting down VM
12-13 22:00:28.017: W/dalvikvm(1438): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.rss.widgetservice@40ce59f8 with Intent { cmp=com.example.rss/.widgetservice }: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2673)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at com.example.rss.widgetservice.onStart(widgetservice.java:44)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2656)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     ... 10 more
```

Here is the code:

Please some one help me to understand this!

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.Service;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class widgetservice extends Service {  
      @Override  
      public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {  
         RemoteViews rviews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);  
         DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
         ComponentName meuWidget = new ComponentName(this, widget.class);  
         AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);  
         try {  
             rviews.setTextViewText(R.id.TextView01, "Updating...");  
             manager.updateAppWidget(meuWidget, rviews);  
             Log.d("widget", "Beginning update cycle...");  
             DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
             Document dom = builder.parse("http://blog.masterd.pt/index.php/feed/");  
             Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();  
             NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("item");  
             if (items.getLength() > 0) {  
                Element entrada = (Element) items.item(0);  
                NodeList titulos = entrada.getElementsByTagName("title");  
                Element titulo = (Element) titulos.item(0);  
                String texto = titulo.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();  
                rviews.setTextViewText(R.id.TextView01, texto);  
                Log.d("widget", "Update cycle completed!");  
                manager.updateAppWidget(meuWidget, rviews);  
             }  
        }  
        catch(Exception ex) {  
            Log.d("widget", ex.getMessage());  
        }  
      }  

      @Override  
         public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {  
           return null;  
        }  
      }
```

And here is my manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rss"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="com.example.rss.widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info">
                        </meta-data>
            </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rss.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.example.rss.widgetservice" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And My widget provider

```
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class widget  extends AppWidgetProvider {


    @Override  
    public void onUpdate(Context context,   
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,  
        int[] appWidgetIds) {  
      Log.d("widget", "onUpdate()");  
      context.startService(new Intent(context, widgetservice.class));  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "don't work" means.

Comment: This work only on devices with 2.3.3 api 10 or 9 or 8. devices with 4.2.2 api 17 for example simply dont work(error while opening and no feed show)

Comment: something has been changed since api 10 with the widget services?? i really cant find why dont work on 4.2.2 api17...

Comment: "error while opening" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "error".

Comment: Thanks for the answers! ive updated the post with logcat while try running on 4.2.2 device

Comment: no one makes idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
12-13 22:00:28.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1438):     at com.example.rss.widgetservice.onStart(widgetservice.java:44)
```

**java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message**

Seems that `ex.getMessage()` returns null at this block

```
catch(Exception ex) {  
    Log.d("widget", ex.getMessage());  
}
```

Change code to this:

```
catch(Exception ex) {  
    String error = (ex.getMessage()==null)?"Some message error":ex.getMessage();
    Log.d("widget", error);  
}
```

Comment: you rock!! thanks! no more error on adding the widget, but the RSSfeed stills not update... on device 2.3.3 the feed shows... why? any ideia?

Comment: If the catch is reached is because an error occurred. The error message is not present but StackTrace should be. At your original catch block change `Log.d("widget", ex.getMessage());` to `Log.d("widget", ex.printStackTrace());` this show you what it is happens.

Comment: thanks for try to helping, but doing what you sayd i got "The method d(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, void)"

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Change `Log.d("widget", ex.getMessage());` to `ex.printStackTrace();`

Comment: now i got this on logcat: 12-15 13:50:42.064: W/System.err(1594): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-15 13:50:42.073: W/System.err(1594):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
12-15 13:50:42.073: W/System.err(1594):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-15 13:50:42.073: W/System.err(1594):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-15 13:50:42.073: W/System.err(1594):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for your helo! @Ramaral you made me see what is the problem... on honeycomb to jelly bean we have to use async task... so an easy way to get this work on jelly bean was to remove **uses sdk min and max version**
Now all work perfect!!! thanks so much!  case **SOLVED**

Comment: Not sure if that will solve the problem. Have you tried in a real device? Google for `NetworkOnMainThreadException` to find the proper way to deal with that

Comment: yeaps, its solved! just changed the target api in manifest to api 9 and now works on any version, include real devices 4.2.2 :)